# Transform T4 templates with MSBuild

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

When trying to transform T4 templates, I got this error:

> Loading the include file 'EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or
>   empty string. The transformation will not be run.

I downloaded and installed the VS2013 SDK, Modelling extension, Data Tools... what else?

EF 6 tools [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40762) doesn't seem to work.

The following is an extract of my .csproj:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
```

Comment: More info: the EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude is located here, but it seems not to find it: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution (I don't like it, but it works) adding this in the .csproj in the same section as explained above:

```
<IncludeFolders>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes</IncludeFolders>
```

Then I got stucked again with [this error](http://romiller.com/2013/03/21/processor-named-t4vshost-could-not-be-found-for-the-directive-named-cleanupbehavior/) and fixed it as explained.